# use of numpy.newaxis in machine learning

Tags: python, numpy, machine-learning

I am trying to increase dimensionality of my inital array:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from sklearn.preprocessing import PolynomialFeatures
x = 10*rng.rand(50)
y = np.sin(x) + 0.1*rng.rand(50)

poly = PolynomialFeatures(7, include_bias=False)
poly.fit_transform(x[:,np.newaxis])
```

First, I know np.newaxis is creating additional column. Why is this necessary?

Now I will train the updated x data(poly) with linear regression

```
test_x = np.linspace(0,10,1000)
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression

model = LinearRegression()
# train with increased dimension(x=poly) with its target
model.fit(poly,y)
# testing
test_y = model.predict(x_test)
```

When I run this it give me :ValueError: Expected 2D array, got scalar array instead: on model.fit(poly,y) line. I've already added a dimension to poly, what is happening?

Also what's the difference between x[:,np.newaxis] Vs. x[:,None]?

Answer (score 1):

```
In [55]: x=10*np.random.rand(5)                                                 
In [56]: x                                                                      
Out[56]: array([6.47634068, 6.25520837, 7.58822106, 4.65466951, 2.35783624])
In [57]: x.shape                                                                
Out[57]: (5,)
```

`newaxis` does not add a column, it adds a dimension:

```
In [58]: x1 = x[:,np.newaxis]                                                   
In [59]: x1                                                                     
Out[59]: 
array([[6.47634068],
       [6.25520837],
       [7.58822106],
       [4.65466951],
       [2.35783624]])
In [60]: x1.shape                                                               
Out[60]: (5, 1)
```

`np.newaxis` has the value of `None`, so both work the same.

```
In[61]: x[:,None].shape                                                        
Out[61]: (5, 1)
```

One is a little clearer to human readers, the other a little easier to type.
https://www.numpy.org/devdocs/reference/constants.html

Whether `x` or `x1` works depends on the expectations of the learning code.  Some learning code expects inputs of the shape `(samples, features)`.  It could assume that a (50,) shape array is 50 samples, 1 feature, or 1 case, 50 features.  But it's better if you tell exactly what you mean.

---

Look at the docs:

https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.PolynomialFeatures.html#sklearn.preprocessing.PolynomialFeatures.fit_transform

```
poly.fit_transform
X : numpy array of shape [n_samples, n_features]
```

Sure looks like `fit_transform` expects a 2d input.

https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.LinearRegression.html#sklearn.linear_model.LinearRegression.fit

Both `X` and `y` are supposed to be 2d.

Comment: adding column is like adding dimension isn't it? for example, if you have [x,y] and you want to add additional column z it will become [x,y,z] 3-D space.

Comment: Are `x` and `y` single points, or the values for a number of points?  You could describe a set of `n` points with a (n,2) array for 2-d space, or (n,3) for 3-d space.  But both are 2d arrays.  On the other hand, you could define a 2d grid in cartesian space with a (n,m) array(s), or a (n,m,o) in a 3d space.  Definition of `dimension` depends on context.